# Проблема с подсчетом двойной суммы

Tags: c++, математика, олимпиада, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int n;
   double sm = 0;
   cin >> n;
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j) {
         sm += i*i - 2 * j;
      }
   }
   cout << sm;
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что он не работает?

Comment: Сайт, который проверяет, на 3м тесте пишет ошибку.

Comment: Дайте-ка URL, посмотрим...

Comment: Это сайт уника, https://ipc.susu.ru/210-2.html?problem=1078

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой FNL.
https://fnl-library.tk/

Answer (score 6):

Только заметил...

Ну кто же так делает?!!

```
double sm = 0;
```

Это же типично целочисленное значение! Введите 1000, и посмотрите, что вам выведет программа: 3.33165e+11

Замените на `long long`, вот этот код благополучно работает:

```
int main()
{
   long long n;
   long long sm = 0;
   cin >> n;
   for (long long i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      for (long long j = 0; j <= n; ++j) {
         sm += i*i - 2 * j;
      }
   }
   cout << sm;
}
```

Но самое ***правильное*** :) решение (работающее до 55000 с небольшим) — вот:

```
int main()
{
    long long n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << (1+n)*(1+n)*(2*n-5)*n/6;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас связался с одногруппником, оказывается, чтоб сайт хавал мое решение нужно было дописать  cout.precision(0). Но ваше замечание я учел), Спасибо большое!

Comment: Далеко не всегда это сработает! Все же вычисления целочисленные и вычисления с плавающей точкой — это очень разные вещи...

Comment: И, кстати, можно вообще с циклами не заморачиваться... :) — см. дополненный ответ.